# Validación de cadenas para romper ciclo no funciona en Java

Tags: java, bucles

Necesito implementar el juego piedra, papel o tijera. Es jugador vs PC.
Jugador introduce tirada y pc es aleatorio.
Debo validar que jugador ingrese una tirada valida. Para ello uso un ciclo el cual se repite hasta que no ingrese una tirada valida. El problema es que no se rompe al introducir los datos correctos. Este es el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio27 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Piedra papel o tijera con la computadora.");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String jugador = "";

    
    do {
        System.out.println("Turno del jugador (introduzca piedra, papel o tijera): ");
        jugador = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(jugador);
    } while (!jugador.equals("piedra") || !jugador.equals("papel") || !jugador.equals("tijera"));
}
```

}

Imprimo jugador y si muestra el dato introducido por el usuario pero falla al hacer la validación

Comment: Mira tu bucle while y pásalo a español: `mientras jugador sea diferente de "piedra" **O** jugador sea diferente de "papel" **O** jugador sea diferente de "tijera"`. Ahora dime, es posible que jugador sea igual a esas tres cosas a la vez?? Nop, si es igual a "piedra", no va a ser igual a "papel", así que si no es por un lado va a ser por el otro, pero ***SIEMPRE*** va a incumplir una condición, así que siempre se quedará ahí. Lo que quieres que haga es quedarse en el while siempre que sea diferente a ***TODAS*** esas cosas. Y `A TODAS` implica usar `&&`, no `||`

Comment: gracias Benito-B saludos